# Link Master Data Set to another Data Set in Fast Report 3

Tags: fastreport

I wish to link a separate data set (DD_1) to the Master Data set (MD_) in Fast Report 3. Can anyone advise how I do it.

The key field in DD_1 os called "ORDER No." and the key field to which it will link in MD_ is "ORDER NUMBER"

At the moment when I use DD_1 (Total Cost field) it returns the first Total Cost record for all the MD_ records. The result should show different, matching, costs for each MD_ record (linked by matching order numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You should create Master-Detail link between datasets on the application level

Comment: Thanks. I worked out the issue was that I was using the same table/field in both data sets, which is not allowed. So I renamed the table in the second dataset which allowed it to work.